# Neo4j start trouble?

Tags: neo4j

I get the following error for all the below mentioned error: What could be problem. Is the problem with java path OR the Neo4j package itself, as some of the stack overflow answer suggest OR linux permission issue?

Starting Neo4j.

```
./neo4j: line 149: /usr/Neo/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.6/bin/run/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory
-bash-4.1$ ./neo4j: line 148: /usr/Neo/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.6/bin/logs/neo4j.log: No such file or directory
```

For all the below version:
neo4j-community-3.1.0-BETA1  or 
neo4j-enterprise-3.0.6 or
neo4j-enterprise-3.1.0-BETA1

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the paths, you'll see that it's trying to write files in sub-directories under `bin`, whereas they are actually next to `bin`:

> /usr/Neo/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.6/**bin/run**/neo4j.pid
>
> /usr/Neo/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.6/**bin/logs**/neo4j.log

Even though you should be able to start Neo4j from inside the `bin` directory, it seems on your machine it fails to determine the base Neo4j directory. Is bash installed? Or have you set `NEO4J_HOME` to `/usr/Neo/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.6/bin` in your shell?

Try starting Neo4j directly from its base directory instead:

```
cd /usr/Neo/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.6
bin/neo4j start
```

Comment: You may also want to login as the owner of the neo4j server. If the owner of the installation is "neo4j" user, then login as neo4j and then start the server.